# Android ListView to Create a Form

Tags: android, listview

I'm very new to Android development. I'm trying to create a "form." In the iOS counterpart app I built, I use a UITableView with static cells. I was able to create each cell differently with different UI Controls. Some had a switch, others had text fields, and others were buttons that would segue to another UIView.

I want to replicate this with Android. Would I use a ListView to create a form?

```
LEFT SIDE                      RIGHT SIDE
Label (Make)                   Label (display make that user picked) *
Label (Model)                  Label (display make that user picked) *
Label (Year)                   Label (display year that user picked) *
Label (Current Location)       Label ON/OFF switch
Label (Zip)                    Text Field

* The first three will take users to another activity which will be a ListActivity. These cells will be dynamic, uniform, and will only contain a label in the cell. Very Basic.
```

The reason why I want to do a ListView is because I like the divider lines and it keeps everything so uniform. I just want to make it as similar as possible to my iOS version of the app.

Any best practices? Also, I'm assuming I won't need an array of the text contents in the `values > arrays.xml` file, right?

Thanks.

Comment: A `ListView` is not an appropriate view on Android to write a form with. They're typically used to present data, not consume it. If you put an EditText in a ListView you're gonna have a bad time.

Comment: So would I use something like the Preferences API to build something like this?

Comment: you could extend PreferenceFragment if it was a screen like Android settings. From what it sounds like, you'll want just a regular layout, and you'd use a style sheet (styles.xml for example) to keep it looking consistent with other parts of your app. To keep it consistent with other forms on other apps - what consistency :P If you adhere to the grids spec, you'll achieve what I think you're after. [link to grid spec](http://developer.android.com/design/style/metrics-grids.html)

Comment: _The reason why I want to do a ListView is because I like the divider lines_ <- this!